# Adding a second set of column names to a data frame

Tags: r, names

I have the following data frame (df1):

```
     C1   C2   C3  C4
R1   11   21   31  a1
R2   de   bc   cc  b
R3   dc   ec   dc  c
R4   gc   gc   gc  d
```

Can I add to the columns names for each 2 names together and get the following data frame (df2):

```
        C12      C34
     C1   C2   C3  C4
R1   11   21   31  a1
R2   de   bc   cc  b
R3   dc   ec   dc  c
R4   gc   gc   gc  d
```

C12 and C34 should be added so I can obtain subsets with df2(C12):

```
       C12     
     C1   C2  
R1   11   21   
R2   de   bc   
R3   dc   ec   
R4   gc   gc
```

Comment: as far as I know, you can't do that. but maybe you can use a named list here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any way to add a second set of column names to a data frame. That being said, you could pretty easily achieve this functionality by creating vectors containing the desired column names:

```
C12 <- c("C1", "C2")
C34 <- c("C3", "C4")
df1[C12]
#    C1 C2
# R1 11 21
# R2 de bc
# R3 dc ec
# R4 gc gc
df1[C34]
#    C3 C4
# R1 31 a1
# R2 cc  b
# R3 dc  c
# R4 gc  d
```

If you instead wanted to subset by rows, you can just use row names:

```
R12 <- c("R1", "R2")
R34 <- c("R3", "R4")
df1[R12,]
#    C1 C2 C3 C4
# R1 11 21 31 a1
# R2 de bc cc  b
df1[R34,]
#    C1 C2 C3 C4
# R3 dc ec dc  c
# R4 gc gc gc  d
```